# Refresh page after action in javascript

Tags: javascript, image, crop

I have the following code, that let users crop their pictures. What I try to do, is to refresh the page after the user croped his picture, to let him see the thumbnail preview. But I tried to put a refresh code every single place, and the refresh never work. Any idea on how I can do this? (Or any idea on what I'm doing wrong?)

**EDIT: I want to do the same as http://demos.9lessons.info/cropimages/imagecrop.php but without the confirm window**

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
 function getSizes(im, obj) {
     var x_axis = obj.x1;
     var x2_axis = obj.x2;
     var y_axis = obj.y1;
     var y2_axis = obj.y2;
     var thumb_width = obj.width;
     var thumb_height = obj.height;
     if (thumb_width > 0) {

         $.ajax({
                 type: "GET",
                 url: "ajax_image.php?t=ajax&img=" + $("#image_name").val() + "&w=" +  thumb_width + "&h=" + thumb_height + "&x1=" + x_axis + "&y1=" + y_axis,
                 cache: false,
                 success: function (rsponse)

            {
                     $("#cropimage").hide();
                     $("#thumbs").html("");
                     $("#thumbs").html("<img src='images/" + response + "' />");
                         complete: function() {
                         location.reload(true);
                         }
                 }

             });

     } else
          alert("Please select portion..!");
 }
 $(document).ready(function () {
     $('img#photo').imgAreaSelect({
         aspectRatio: '1:1',
         onSelectEnd: getSizes
     });
 });

</script>
```

Comment: Any errors being thrown?

Comment: Well the user crop his picture, and after it never refresh to the new cropped thumbnail, it's always the old, until I manually refresh the page.

Comment: @freddy `rsponse` is a typo. You might also have caching issues if you are requesting the same image src. You can simply add a random param to the src url to fix your problem.

Comment: I'm not requesting the same image src. I just whant to find a way to automaticlly refresh the page, cause what I want can be achieve with a manual refresh...

Comment: @freddy, did you tried to put the refresh code in your success callback?

Comment: could it be the value of "images/" + response != the actual location of the image - perhaps the rsponse typo? what does alert(response) yield at that point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your page refresh code in complete call back

**Example:**

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "ajax_image.php?t=ajax&img=" + $("#image_name").val() + "&w=" +  thumb_width + "&h=" + thumb_height + "&x1=" + x_axis + "&y1=" + y_axis,
    cache: false,
    success: function (rsponse) {
        $("#cropimage").hide();
        $("#thumbs").html("");
        $("#thumbs").html("<img src='images/" + response + "' />");
    },
    complete: function() {
        location.reload(true);
    }
});
```

Hope this will help !!

Comment: @freddy, you have added it at wrong place, I posted the correct code in my answer.